# "from" or "of" for "the extraction .... page"

Tags: prepositions

I wrote:

> There are many approaches to perform the main content extraction **of** web pages.

could it be **from** web pages? because **extraction** usually gets **from** preposition, but I usually hear ...tion of something...

Answer (score 1):

If the webpage is performing the extraction, then 'of' is appropriate. If the content is being extracted from the webpage, 'from' is more appropriate.